# Will importing SSL certificates for iOS push notifications prevent other developers from working on the project?

Tags: ios, git, push-notification, ssl-certificate

I'm implementing push notifications in my iOS app, and as the primary developer, the completed app will be put on my account. However, there is another developer working on this app via GitHub, and he does not currently have access to my apple developer account. (He does, however, have a separate account.)

If I configure the certificates for my branch of the project, and he tries pulling in the changes, will he receive compile errors for not having the certificates? If so, is there a way I can proceed without giving him access to my apple account and its information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The push notification certificate is provided to the push notification server to enable it to authenticate with the Apple servers.  It is tied to the bundle ID that you register on the developer account, but it isn't embedded in your source code or your project.

If your other developer is using their own developer account to sign test builds for use on their devices, then their builds will be linked to a different bundle.  They will still be able to compile and run code, but they will not be able to push notifications using your notification server.  They can generate their own certificates on their own developer account and register this certificate with a push notification service if they want.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate for push notifications is used server-side and is not part of the application bundle, so it will not have a direct impact on other developers working on the same project (i.e. they can still work on it making builds etc), however for the apns to function there are other considerations besides the push notification certificate.

To configure your app to use apns you will need to set up an app id (this links to a bundle identifier that must be in the applications info.plist). With an app id you can enable the push notification service and get the certificate by submitting a certificate signing request .csr (this can be done with the Key Chain Access application and uses your developer certificate, which links to your developer private key!)

And the final piece of the puzzle is to generate a provisioning profile for the app id (and this is the glue that makes it all work). You must build the application with an appropriate provisioning profile for the service to work.

So to summarise the app id, developer certificate, developer private key, push notification certificate, provisioning profile, and physical devices are all linked together.